# Laravel time format

Tags: php, laravel

I figured out how to format date:
in model:

```
protected $dates = ['date'];
```

in view:

```
{{ $date->format('d/m') }}
```

How to display time in format h:m?

```
{{ $time }} this displays time h:m:s
```

Comment: http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/02/11/formatting-timestamps-in-laravel/

Comment: This works for date, but how to make it work for time?

Comment: You have to pass the format string to the date object as described in that doc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
{{\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s',$time)->format('h:i')}}
```

Comment: how to display AM and PM?

Comment: You can find the format in here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php just pass the right letter in the `format('g:i A')` or `format(g:i a')`